local folder image not loading issue in MAUI
I have a MAUI app. I am creating folder call Theme inside the device. and my images are there. When I tried to get the image my path FileSystem.AppDataDirectory  shows following file path. So I tried to remove this files part manually and tried but i am getting null value.  This theme folder is inside the App folder like files folder.
 var themeFolder = Path.Combine("/data/user/0/com.company.android.myproject/files", "Theme");
 var filePath = Path.Combine(themeFolder, "logo.png");

 if (File.Exists(filePath))
 {
     return ImageSource.FromFile(filePath);
 }

Please correct me is there any mistake. Thank you!

What's the value of the File.Exists(filePath)? I can get the correct imagesource by your code from your path if the file is existed.

Are these files bundled with your app, or created at runtime?

@Jason those are created at runtime. I am downloading these files from server and created Theme folder

@ Liyun Zhang - MSFT   I am stuck with the file path. I am not getting correct file path

Can you show the code about creating the Theme folder and saving image files? The correct file path is that you used to create and saving files.
